# Django Rest API TypeError when using ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I encountered a `TypeError` when trying to use the `ChoiceField` in my serializers.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.fields import ChoiceField

from comp_track_sys.models import Campaign
from contacts.models import CList

class EditCampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditCampaignSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.context['request'].user
        clists = CList.objects.filter(company=user.profile.company)
        self.fields['clist'] = ChoiceField(choices=clists)
```

I have tried to do `ChoiceField(choices=json.dumps(clists))`, but still got the error.

```
TypeError: <CList: Testing> is not JSON serializable
```

These are my models in case it is needed to resolve the issue.

```
# Campaign Model
class Campaign(models.Model):
    campaign_id = UUIDField(auto=True)
    name = models.CharField("Campaign Name", max_length=50)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    clist = models.ForeignKey(CList, verbose_name="Contact List", blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

# CList Model
class CList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Contact List", max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='con_clists')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uuid = models.CharField("ShortUUID", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

This is the views

```
class EditCampaignViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EditCampaignSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def list(self, request, type=None, *args, **kwargs):
        company = request.user.company
        queryset = Campaign.objects.filter(company=company,
                                           campaign_type=type)\
                                   .order_by('-created')\
                                   .prefetch_related('user__profile')
        serializer = EditCampaignSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': self.request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: If this is just to link a `CList` to a `Campaign` why not use a `SlugRelatedField`? Or was there a specific reason why you wanted to use a `ChoiceField`?

Comment: The reason for the usage of ChoiceField is because I wanted the user to be able to create new campaign as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` rather than a `ChoiceField`, and defining a custom `get_queryset` method on the serializer field to filter the relevant `QuerySet`.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.fields import ChoiceField

from comp_track_sys.models import Campaign
from contacts.models import CList

class CListPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(
           company=self.root.context['request'].user.profile.company
        )

class EditCampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    clist = CListPrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=CList.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = (
            'clist',
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `ChoiceField` you need to make sure that the `choices` keyword is some iterable. By using `json.dumps(clists)` I imagine you were trying to convert your `clists` into an iterable however, the `CList` type cannot be JSON serialized because it isn't recognized by the json library.

Once you pick a field you want to set as valid choices you might be able to try something like this, for example if the field you wanted to choose from was the primary key:

```
ChoiceField(choices=list(clists.values_list('pk', flat=True)))
```

Since the `.values_list` method returns an iterable, this will be fine to pass to `choices=`.

Hope I helped.

Comment: You may want to check if ChoiceField actually takes a list of tuples,  i.e. `[('no', 'No'), ('yes', 'Yes')]`

Comment: Yes, you are correct however `ChoiceField` can also just accept a iterable of valid values rather than a mapping: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#choicefield

Comment: @mattjegan I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work either. Still got the same TypeError

Comment: @chronox a JSON serializer TypeError or a different kind? I'm not sure why this wouldn't work and I don't think you would be getting a JSON error if we are no longer using json.dumps. Can you add your view to the question as well please?

Comment: @mattjegan yes still getting the <CList: Testing> is not JSON serializable error. I will update my question to include the view

Comment: @chronox sorry my arguments were in the wrong order in my answer, give that a shot

Comment: @mattjegan yup, I already switched the arguments order. Still getting the same error

Comment: @chronox also make sure to include the `list()` caste since the values list may be a queryset depending on django version

Comment: I added in the list for the values list, but still encountering the same issue.